# Как ускорить передачу данных, tcp

Tags: оптимизация, tcp, tcp-ip

Как ускорить передачу пакетов через tcp протокол желательно больше 1 мб/сек, какие есть идеи?

Думал как нибудь распараллелить передачу, например на клиенте создать 4 подключения (что-то типа потоков ;D) к серверу, пакет разбить на 4 части и отправлять эти пакеты одновременно, но я не знаю будет ли это быстрее, то-что они будут приходить не одновременно и потом при склейке возможна путаница я знаю, скажите пожалуйста, хороша ли моя идея или дичь какая-то и как тогда сделать лучше?

Comment: @Mike то-есть если в торренте у меня скорость доходит 4,5 мб/сек, то я в c# при передаче данных через обычный буффер могу серверу без какой либо оптимизации выжать такую же скорость?

Comment: @Mike ну ладно,ответьте, а я проголосую

Comment: @Mike ну а вот как параллельные сессии сделать, так же как и я сказал, просто 3 разных соединения сделать на трёх разных портах?

Comment: ну да, просто 3 соединения. А дальше уже пользоваться особенностями прикладного протокола что бы запросить по каждому из соединений разные части информации. И да, порты на клиенте разные, на сервере он может быть один (обычно так и есть)

Comment: Ну насчёт 2 пункта всё и так понятно, если у клиента комп донный, то тут уже не чего не поделаешь ) Отвечайте уже :0)

Comment: что бы передавать быстро - нужно держать буффера чтения записи оптимально наполненными. Если отправлять по одному байту, то хороших скоростей не получить. Если отправлять хотя бы по 4к, то скорость может существенно вырасти. Также скорость зависит от пинга между участниками.

Comment: @KoVadim 4k = 4000 байт ?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy Ну в большинстве случаев на маршруте используется ethernet так что фактически скорость передачи пакета с 1 байтом информации и пакета с 1500 (минус длина заголовков) одинакова. поэтому надо что бы когда ядро собралось слать пакет у него в буфере был уже этот объем целиком, а так как передача происходит быстро, то конечно лучше, что бы там было готово к отправке гораздо больше.

Comment: Ну я короче вас понял, что нужно плотненько забивать пакет для отправки

Comment: 4к это 4096 байт. Или Вы производитель жёстких дисков?:). В любом случае, размер подбирается экспериментально под заданные условия для максимальной скорости.

Comment: @KoVadim "Или Вы производитель жёстких дисков?:)", аж до слёз ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Протокол TCP позволяет спокойно передавать и на скоростях порядка 1 гигабита. Скорость передачи чаще всего ограничена чисто техническими вещами на маршруте между клиентом и сервером.

Разделение передачи контента на несколько параллельных подключений может увеличить суммарную  скорость только в 2х случаях:

- На сервере стоит явное искусственное ограничение на скорость по одному подключению
- На канале связи между клиентом и сервером периодически теряются пакеты. TCP достаточно долго восстанавливается после потерь пакетов (выжидает таймауты и повторяет передачу) в итоге передача на некоторое время приостанавливается. При этом другое TCP соединение в это же время может спокойно передавать.

Comment: Или если пакеты уходят быстро, а подтверждения доходят долго, и размера окна не хватает